# Naming this organic compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What’s the name of the following compound?

$$\ce{CH3C(p-ClC6H4)2CH(Br)CH3}$$

My teacher said that she strongly thinks( with another teacher) that it should be **3-bromo-2,2-bis-(4-chlorophenyl)butane**, though many other books and other students (similar to me) stated that it should be **2-bromo-3,3-bis-(4-chlorophenyl)butane**.

She asked us try to find it out. Any organic chemistry experts out there?

Answer (score 0):

I think your teacher is correct, numbering of carbons is done acording to the lowest locant rule.
[image: numbering]

The red numbering gives you : 2, **3**, 3

The green numbering gives you : 2, **2**, 3

We see that the first point of difference between the two numberings occurs at second number, so the green numbering is preferred.
Consequently, the correct name should be : **3-Bromo-2,2-bis(4-chlorophenyl)butane**